# My app cant update cache while pwa is active on laravel

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm making an application with PWA but when in the database I update something in the main URL that appears no changes have occurred, and I have to clear the cache that is in the service worker, whereas in mobile, the end user might not have to clear the cache first to use the application. , is there a solution to my problem?

I have done several alternatives such as masking the URL to avoid caching the service worker but I know it's not efficient

it's my service worker file

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workboxcdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js');
if (workbox) {


    workbox.setConfig({
        debug: true
    });
    // top-level routes we want to precache
    workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(['/123', '/123']);

    // injected assets by Workbox CLI
    workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([

    //my precache data is here
    ]);

    // match routes for homepage, blog and any sub-pages of blog
    workbox.routing.registerRoute(
        /^\/(?:()?(\/.*)?)$/,
        new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
            cacheName: 'static-resources',
        })
    );

    // js/css files
    workbox.routing.registerRoute(
        /\.(?:js|css)$/,
        new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
            cacheName: 'static-resources',
        })
    );

    // images
    workbox.routing.registerRoute(
        // Cache image files.
        /\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/,
        // Use the cache if it's available.
        new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
            // Use a custom cache name.
            cacheName: 'image-cache',
            plugins: [
                new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
                    // Cache upto 50 images.
                    maxEntries: 50,
                    // Cache for a maximum of a week.
                    maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
                })
            ],
        })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any logic in your service worker to invalidate cached data/responses when you post updates to the server. You will have to add that logic to your fetch handler.

FYI workbox does not include that by default you will have to create your own logic for that. Workbox only has some common caching strategies in place. It can't provide modules for every site's custom caching scenarios. That is why the tool is extensible.